# Making warmup cards with LaTeX

Tags: learning

I'd like to make warmup cards using LaTeX.

- 2 questions per page
- Optional Title at the top
- The question should be at the top
- The bottom right corner should have a box of adjustable size.
- Ideally, the setup would be structured in the form of an environment.

Comment: I guess you won't get much help, unless you show us what you have tried so far and where exactly you're stuck at. "Do this for me" kind of questions are seldomly answered...

Comment: In first instance, you should look at package tcolorbox. Should be done easily with it.

Comment: Thanks, @TomášKruliš. This appears to be a very promising direction. I'll post back a response when I've got something going.

Comment: @AlexVaughn I chose to notify you about that package since it is (in my opinion) very versatile and very well documented, and for someone starting off might be usable. Still, you should follow the first comment - try to create something, test it, that post a question. Ideally with specific problem.